# How to save scraped data to csv unsing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to save my scraped data to csv file using pandas. But I keep getting a bug.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

link = ("https://sofifa.com/team/1/arsenal/?&showCol%5B%5D=ae&showCol%5B%5D=hi&showCol%5B%5D=le&showCol%5B%5D=vl&showCol%5B%5D=wg&showCol%5B%5D=rc")
get_text = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text.content, "lxml") 
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"table table-hover persist-area"})
table1 = table.get_text()

table1.to_csv("Arsenal_players.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first read the html into a pandas dataframe using [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), and then use `to_csv` to write to a file. Here is an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

link = ("https://sofifa.com/team/1/arsenal/?&showCol%5B%5D=ae&showCol%5B%5D=hi&showCol%5B%5D=le&showCol%5B%5D=vl&showCol%5B%5D=wg&showCol%5B%5D=rc")
get_text = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"table table-hover persist-area"})

# produces a list of dataframes from the html, see docs for more options
dfs = pd.read_html(str(table)) 
dfs[0].to_csv("Arsenal_players.csv")
```

The `read_html` method has quite a few options that can change the behavior. You can also use it to read your link directly instead of first using requests/BeautifulSoup (it can do that under the hood).

It might look something like this, but this is untested because that link gives a 403 forbidden when I do this (perhaps they are blocking based on user agent):

```
dfs = pd.read_html(link, attrs={"class":"table table-hover persist-area"})
```

EDIT: since read_html doesn't allow you to specify a user agent, I believe this will end up being the most concise way for this particular link:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(
    requests.get(link).text,
    attrs={"class":"table table-hover persist-area"}
)
dfs[0].to_csv("Arsenal_players.csv")
```

Comment: Kindly explain why "[0]"  is added to "dfs".

Comment: See the comment in the first bit of code, as well as the documentation for read_html. It returns a list of dataframes for matching html tables found in the input html. The OP's table of interest happens to be the first one, but he/she should make sure the attribute filtering is specific enough to isolate to one table if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter more explanation before asking a question like type of error you get this will be more helpful to give the answer. Anyway I run your code and see the error as expected.
well table1 variable only consist strings now because of

```
table1 = table.get_text()
```

so there is no function in your situation to enter all data in csv but you can find help [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_saving_dataframe_as_csv/).
But remember for next time be precise about your problem.